# How to add a property to the request object type in Express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have created a custom middleware that performs some logic.

It takes the `req.body` and flips the keys as values and values as keys. Both the keys and the values are strings, I also have validation so there's nothing to worry about.

The result is stored on the `req` object as `req.$mappedBody` so that I can use this property on the next middleware in the request/response stack.

So it's similar to this form:

```
const mapFields = (map) => (req, res, next) => { / * logic * / }
```

```
// app.ts

const app = express()

app.get('/', authentication, validation, mapFields(arg), (r,s,n)=>{n()}, 
(r,s,n) => { 
 console.log(r.$mappedBody); 
 n() 
})
```

Of course, my `mapFields` is a generic function, but to simplify this question I omitted the logic.

I want to see autocompletion for the property `$mappedBody`, in the next middleware, TypeScript thinks that this property called `$mappedBody` does not exist on the `req` object, when it does.

Also, I know I can do type casting here, and say something like:

```
interface createUserRequest extends Request {
  $mappedBody: I don't know, the type.
} 
(req: createUserRequest, res, next) => {
  req.$mappedBody.hey
}
```

But doing this everywhere is not so good, so isn't there a way I can do it at the top, and then the rest of the flow will assume it's available?

Comment: I don't know with Express, but I know Fastify handles this well.

Comment: @merryweather, can you share a link or something to fastify I am also curious to see how they solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type for the `$mappedBody`. The type would look something like this:

```
type $MappedBody<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in keyof T as `${T[K]}`]: K;
};
```

You can then use this type in the `createUserRequest` interface.

Edit: I misunderstood OP's question. To hook the `$mappedBody` property to the `Request` type of express do the following:

Create a `types.d.ts` file (the name of the file does not matter)

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        $mappedBody: YOUR TYPE
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to hang the property onto the request object, I know the type, it's not hard to infer it. The idea is to avoid doing the _`createUserRequest` interface_ approach

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I have added an example of how to add your own properties to the `Request` interface

Comment: great!, how can ensue this will only run when I use my custom middleware? so that this property called "$mappedBody" will not exist if I did not use the mapFields middleware?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not something you can do sadly... You would have to create your own interface/type with the added property if you want to make sure it only exists on the routes that use your middleware

Comment: Hi, Can you revise the `declare namespace Express`?  as it seems like it does not work with me

Comment: You could try declaring it as a module instead of a namespace.